# I want to change the value of an option button in a user form via its name in a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button

I have some option buttons set up such as stp1, stp2, stp3, etc.
I have something that which is active into a cell, I want to be able to re-activate the option button via its name which is placed in the cell B6.

I tried many thing here is an example:

```
Worksheets("Data").Select
[B6].Value = oSel 'Option button select
oSel.Value = True 'as to re-activate the option button
```

I recieved the name by using:

```
For Each Control In Me.Controls
    If InStr(Control.Name, "stp") Then
        If Control.GroupName = "Beginning" Then
            If Control.Value = True Then
                oSel = Control.Name
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

If you could help I would really appreciate it, and if I forgot some important information or you just need more... just ask. I am fairly new to VBA and I am experimenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not entirely sure what you require, this simple 'bare-bones' example should take you forward.  It allows you to select a radio button on the userform which updates cell 'B6' and also put the radio button name in cell 'B6' which updates the userform.  Cell 'B6' is on a sheet called 'Data'

Assumes a userform called UserForm1 and three radio buttons named stp1, stp2 and stp3 as shown.  Note that for this example you should set the `ShowModal` property of UserForm1 to `False` and set the 'GroupName' property of each radio button to 'Beginning'.  Run the example by selecting/running the UserForm1 module.

[image: Example]

Put this code in a general module.

```
Sub chk()
Set sel = Sheets("Data").Range("B6")
    With UserForm1
        For Each Control In .Controls
            If Control.GroupName = "Beginning" Then
                If Control.Name = sel.Value Then
                    Control.Value = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Put this code in the UserForm1 module

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call chk
End Sub

Private Sub stp1_Click()
    With Me
        Sheets("Data").Range("B6").Value = "stp1"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub stp2_Click()
    With Me
        Sheets("Data").Range("B6").Value = "stp2"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub stp3_Click()
    With Me
        Sheets("Data").Range("B6").Value = "stp3"
    End With
End Sub
```

Put this code in 'Data' Sheet module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sel As Range
Set sel = Sheets("Data").Range("B6")
    If Target = sel Then
        Call chk
    End If
End Sub
```

These last pieces of code may introduce you to the concept of 'events' and how to begin using them.

Comment: Thankyou that first block of coding is just what I needed I am trying to create an adventure game and you can move around with option buttons I am creating save/load and I needed to store position data I was able to save the data but I needed the code you have so wonderfully provided me with in order to load the position :) again thankyou

Comment: Perhaps you would mark this as your answer to tidily close off this post. Glad it helped to move you forward.